# Who is the largest being in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

There are only three beings I know of in the MCU that are big, but I can't tell which one is the biggest. Which one of these being is biggest, and is there anyone bigger than that?

- Dormammu
- Knowhere (or rather, the Celestials when they were alive)
- Ego the planet

Comment: Tony Stark's self-importance.

Comment: We catch a glimpse of a Celestial in GotG: https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marvelmovies/images/b/b5/Celestials.png and it appears to be short enough to fit within a planet's atmosphere - so it's probably between several kilometers and several dozen kilometers tall. Since Knowhere was once the head of a Celestial, I'm inclined to believe that Knowhere is the size of a large city, not a small planet.

Comment: What about Galactus? He's pretty big. Much bigger than Dormammu

Comment: Galactus isn't in the MCU...yet

Comment: What unit of measurement? Like, size? story-arc? ego (lol, get it?)?

Comment: @Möoz: Knowhere is not a contender for largest story arc, so this must be about physical size.  There is simply no other plausible interpretation of the word "biggest."

Comment: My point is that comparing "biggest" is fraught with varied interpretations and justifications. It's simply not a very well defined question. Interesting, just not quite on spec for a "good" question on this site.

Comment: Also, you've said largest "person" in the title, in sure you meant being right? Then, in the body, you say biggest "things"; this can be confusing to people as "things" usually includes inanimate objects, so that could include a super-massive black hole or other large object.

Comment: @recognizer: “it appears to be short enough to fit within a planet's atmosphere - so it's probably between several kilometers and several dozen kilometers tall”. Most likely. Of course, I guess we can’t be sure how big the planet in question is? It could be the size of a million Egos! If only there was a banana in shot for scale.

Comment: @Kevin: “Knowhere is not a contender for largest story arc” — if we look at the amount of time involved (from living Celestials, to other being using the dead head of one to mine), it’s gotta be a contender.

Comment: @Paul: I simply can't believe someone would use the word "biggest" in that sense, rather than either size or screen time.

Comment: Look deep within yourself, @Kevin. You have the capacity to believe. Join us! Stretch reasonable interpretation further than anyone thinks possible!

Comment: @Paul: I am not voting to close on the basis of a deliberate misinterpretation of the question.

Comment: Isn't Eternity supposed to be the entire Marvel universe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, the largest being whose size was *shown* in MCU media is [Arishem](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Arishem_the_Judge) (a [Celestial](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Celestials)).

In his appearance in *Eternals*, he is revealed to be approximately the same size as the earth. For comparison, Ego's planet is "no larger than [...] earth's moon" according to Ego in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*.

[image: Arishem]

Also shown in *Eternals* is [Tiamut](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Tiamut_the_Communicator) (another Celestial). His form was revealed as a vision to Sersi by Arishem. He is also shown to be around the size of the earth.

[image: Tiamut][image: Tiamut]
[image: Tiamut][image: Tiamut]
[image: Tiamut][image: Tiamut]

Answer (score 6):

Considering the options you gave, the answer would probably be **Dormammu**. However, his appearance in *Doctor Strange* only appears to be a reflection of the titular character himself, so his true corporeal form may be undefined.

Given that, another answer up for consideration would have to be **Ego**, for obvious reasons. He is a planet, after all. However, considering the fact that he is a Celestial, there may be others of his species that are even larger. I suppose we won't know until *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3*.

Comment: However.... Ego isn't "that big". Ego is just the brain

Answer (score -2):

The largest character is The Living Tribunal he has to power to increase his size an infinite amount. Basically, he can be bigger than every other character if he wants to. The second biggest and third biggest are the Oblivion entity and the Eternity entity. Their sizes are unknown but they are still bigger than everyone besides The Living Tribunal.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This could be a good answer if you linked to or better quoted some sources for this.

Comment: Have any of these been shown in the MCU yet?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist if memory serves one of the artifacts in _Doctor Strange_ was from the Living Tribunal. Not sure about the others